# Ethernet via Thunderbolt display with MacBook Pro 2017 (A1707)?

Tags: macbook-pro, network, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I've connected my new MacBook Pro to my [Apple Thunderbolt display](https://www.apple.com/sg/shop/product/FC914ZP/B/refurbished-thunderbolt-display-27-inch) using the [Apple Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207266). The display and USB are working as expected but I'm not getting any ethernet. Ethernet is working fine with my old Thunderbolt 2 MacBook Pro. Has anyone been able to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this other post provided the hint that I needed to get this working! [MacBook Sierra display ethernet needs constant re-starting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284541/macbook-sierra-display-ethernet-needs-constant-re-starting)

Unplugging the display and then plugging it back in fixed the problem! What a pain!

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I get the external display and USB devices plugged into the monitor are recognized, but no ethernet at all. Was there anything else you had to do to make things work?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://www.apple.com/shop/questions/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter) the trick is:

> To get the ethernet on the display working, I had to disconnect the
>   USB-C adapter, delete (AFAIR) the Thunderbolt Bridge from the network
>   preferences, and then reconnect the adapter.

This worked for me too, I now have Display Ethernet in the network interfaces list.

Comment: Thanks for this great tip, which also solved my issues!
Actually I deleted more 'unused' connections from the Network-Preferences. Note that a restart was needed in order to have the desired effect!